# Core Data: Extend Predicate to fetch related entities with special Attribute-Value

Tags: core-data, swift, nspredicate

I've got 2 entities (1 to many), both with a boolean flag "visible"

To fetch all visible Entities of A i use

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"visible != false")
```

This way I get all visible A filled with all B (including the non visible)

**Question**: Is it possible to extend the predicate to fetch all visible A filled only with all visible Entities of B?
Or do I have to loop through all Entities?

Thanks!

**[Update 1]** Here is some code:

```
class A: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var visible: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var relationShipToB: NSSet
}
class B: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var visible: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var relationShipToA: NSManagedObject
}
```

**[Update 2]** This is how my workaround looks like (in Swift)

```
class A: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var visible: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var relationShipToB: NSSet
    var visibleB:[B] {
        get {
            var result = [B]()
            for b in relationShipToB.allObjects as [B] {
                if(b.visible.boolValue) {
                    result.append(b)
                }
            }
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

**[Update 3]**
Lets say we have following instances:

```
A1 {
    visible = "true"
    toB = [B1, B2]
}

A2 {
    visible = "true"
    toB = [B3]
}

B1 {
    visible = "true"
}

B2 {
    visible = "false"
}

B3 {
    visible = "false"
}
```

Expected result:

```
A1 [B1]
A2 []
```

As the result of my request I want to get *A1* and *A2* (both are visible).
But as an containing *A1.toB* I **only** want to have *B1* (*B2* is not visible)
And *A2.toB* will be emty, because *B3* is not visible.

Comment: Please update post with A and B classes code.

Comment: It's possible, you should use ALL operator. It's hard currently to give you ready answer due to lack of the code.

Comment: If the workaround fixed the issue post it as the answer and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code...

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"visible != false && ANY toB.visible != false")
```

... where `toB` is the name of the one-to-many relationship between A and B.

**Edit**

Using NSExpression subquery expressions ([see Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html)), you can write the equivalent of the previous predicate like this:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "visible != false && (SUBQUERY(toB, $x, $x.visible != false).@count != 0)")
```

Those two predicates will allow you to find visible A files that have at least one visible related B managedObject.

If you want to fetch A managedObjects that only have visible related B managedObjects, you can use the predicate given to us by @Shmidt:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"visible != false && ALL toB.visible != false")
```

But the problem there is that Core Data projects based on SQLite (NSSQLiteStoreType Persistent Store Type) can't use predicates that contain "ALL": it generates a compile time error like the one you get ([see this old post from Melissa Turner](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Jun/msg01982.html)).

Fortunately, using once more NSExpression subquery expressions, you can write an (ugly) equivalent of this previous predicate that will work for Core Data SQLite based projects:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "visible != false && (SUBQUERY(toB, $x, $x.visible != false).@count == toB.@count)")
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work, because it's a 1-to-many Relationship. Following error occurs: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'"

Comment: Edited my answer: I had forgotten "ANY" in the predicate.

Comment: See my Edit #2 for a much complete answer.

Comment: Wow, now it is getting complicated :-) But I think, I still want something different. See my updated my Question

Comment: When you do a fetchRequest (with any predicate), the result of this request is a NSArray of managedObjects of the same type. Thus, if you do a fetchRequest on A managedObjects, the result of this fetchRequest will be a NSArray of A managedObjects (not a array of mixed A and B managedObjects). If want you want is in fact to have all B visible objects that have a visible toA relationship, you will have to perform your fetchRequest on B entity. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"visible = true AND ALL relationShipToB.visible = true")
```

Comment: This doesn't work too. I can't use the ALL-Operator (don't know exactly why). Following error occurs: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate visible == 1 AND ALL toB.visible == 1'"

Comment: Same error. A single equality sign will be changed to a double one. Also a given parameter 'true' or 'yes' is automatically changed to '1'.